# Bi-directionality in BERT model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, machine-learning-model, transformer

I am reading the paper *BERT: Pre-training of Deep Bidirectional Transformers for Language Understanding* that can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf).

It looks to me that the crux of the paper is using masked inputs to achieve bidirectionally.

This is an excerpt from the Google AI blog [here](https://ai.googleblog.com/2018/11/open-sourcing-bert-state-of-art-pre.html) which states:

> "However, it is not possible to train bidirectional models by simply
>   conditioning each word on its previous and next words, since this
>   would allow the word that’s being predicted to indirectly “see itself”
>   in a multi-layer model.  To solve this problem, we use the
>   straightforward technique of masking out some of the words in the
>   input and then condition each word bidirectionally to predict the
>   masked words."

Can someone please help me understand how does bidirectionally allow the words to see themselves and how masking solves this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out my answer on Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/446049/24612

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take an example : "I went to the shop."

Let's say you want to predict "to" and "the". With bidirectionality, you will predict :

`p(to | I, went, the, shop)` : No problem here.

`p(the | I, went, to, shop)` : Here we have a problem, because we already saw the word 'the' while predicting 'to'. It's trivial for the model to predict 'the'.

---

With MLM, if we take the same example :

`p(to | I, went, [MASK], [MASK], shop)`
`p(the | I, went, [MASK], [MASK], shop)`

There is no more problem because the word cannot see itself in other predictions. It's more difficult to predict, but anyway only 15% of the time the word is masked.

---

*Edit*

In MLM, BERT will see all the words of the sentence, including the word to predict itself. 
This is because BERT will create representations not only for the [MASK] token, but also for the other tokens of the sentence (but in this case we are interested only in [MASK]).

Note : It is also because BERT will create representations of all tokens that we need to replace [MASK] sometimes by the original token, sometimes by a random token.

You can find more detailed information in [this blog](https://medium.com/dissecting-bert/dissecting-bert-part2-335ff2ed9c73) in the "Pretraining" section.

Comment: With MLM, shouldn't the probability be P(to | I,went, [MASK],shop ) with only one [MASK] ?

Comment: Please see my edit :)